# PHP Memcached delete function not working as expected

Tags: php, memcached

So the problem is that the keys I want to delete from memcached are actually not being removed. I get no errors. At this point I don't really have a clue what the problem could be. It also shows the correct key it wants to delete so there is nothing wrong with that.

Down below my Class for using memcached, does anybody have any clue on what the problem might be? So far I didn't find any clues on what the problem might be or how to fix the problem.

```
class MemCacher extends Memcached{


function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    parent::addServer(MEMCACHED_SERVER,11211,1);

}

function add($p_sKey,$p_oData,$p_iTime = 43200){
    $t_sKey = CACHE_NAME.$p_sKey;
    parent::set($t_sKey,$p_oData,$p_iTime);
}

function get($p_sKey){
    $t_sKey = CACHE_NAME.$p_sKey;
    return parent::get($t_sKey);
}

function remove($p_sKey){
    $t_sKey = CACHE_NAME.$p_sKey;
    parent::delete($t_sKey);
    debug("Deleted:".$t_sKey);
}

function show_all(){
    if( $l_aCacheInfo = parent::getAllKeys() ){
        foreach($l_aCacheInfo as $key){
            if( strpos($key, CACHE_NAME) !== FALSE ){
                debug($key);
            }
        }
    }   
}

function clear_all(){

    if( $l_aCacheInfo = parent::getAllKeys() ){
        foreach($l_aCacheInfo as $key){
            if( strpos($key, CACHE_NAME) !== FALSE ){
               parent::delete($key);
               debug("Deleted:".$key);
            }
        }
    }   
}

}
```

Comment: You might check the return of the `delete()` and then `getResultCode()`.  Also to `clear_all()` you might want to look at `deleteMulti()`.

Answer (score -1):

So apparently the delete method requires the expiration time to be 0 in order to remove it else it doesn't work.

doesn't work

```
parent::delete($t_sKey);
```

works

```
parent::delete($t_sKey,0);
```

Comment: The default value for the second parameter is already 0.